# How to overflow a custom select box that's positioned in a grid so it doesn't extend the row it is in?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have created a custom select box consisting of div elements entirely and placed it inside of my grid layout in 2nd column, 1st row (as you can see in the image below)

[image: custom select box inside of grid issue]

My issue is that whenever I open the select box and it extends the options, the row it is in extends as well. I've tried playing with `overflow` but to no avail.

I need those options to overflow to rows below instead of extending the existing row. How would I go about solving this efficiently?

Comment: Please share the code for better understanding

Comment: Pretty much the only reasonable option is to use `position: absolute`

Comment: @CBroe that crossed my mind but I wanted to dodge it if possible.

Comment: Why? Maybe a negative margin-bottom on the custom select wrapper or something like that would also work - but then you'd probably have to involve JavaScript to calculate the necessary amount.

Comment: You're right, I guess absolute positioning would be the simplest way to achieve this.
I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Positioning the custom select box list of options absolutely as @CBroe recommended worked well enough. Thank you!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).